# Adding regex filter to feedwordpress

Tags: plugins, php, regex, feed

I'm trying to write a plugin for Feedwordpress that filters html from the incoming feeds.
So far I have managed to hook it to the right place, but the function completely wipes all content (and it seems to cause issues with the Feedwordpress plugin).
Where am I going wrong here?

```
add_filter(
    /*hook=*/ 'syndicated_item_content',
    /*function=*/ 'fwp_rss_regex',
    /*order=*/ 10,
    /*arguments=*/ 1
);

function fwp_rss_regex ($post) {
    $content = $post->post_content();   
    $content = preg_replace('\<[^\>]*\>', '', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
function fwp_rss_regex ($content) {
$content = preg_replace('/\<[^\>]*\>/i','',$content);
return $content;
}
```

This solved the problem: 1) Because `$content` was the item I wanted I wanted to pass through fwp_rss_regex, 2) Because I fixed my `preg_replace` with `/______/i` , and 3) I realised `$content = $post->post_content();` was either a superfluous (though maybe valid) command, or was it doing nothing in at all.

Comment: Please explain _why_ this solves the problem.

Comment: This solved the problem: 1) Because `$content` was the item I wanted I wanted to pass through `fwp_rss_regex`, 2) Because I fixed my `preg_replace` with `/______/i` , and 3) I realised `$content = $post->post_content();` was either a superfluous (though maybe valid) command, or was it doing nothing in at all.

Comment: Add your explanation from the comment above as an [edit] to your answer where it belongs :-). Also accept your own answer by clicking on the arrow next to your answer. It will go green which means the answer is accepted as the best solution